# How to quickly remove a pair of parentheses in Vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

I have a document that has thousands of times repeated fragments of this type:

```
( 
   "x" => "a",
   "xxxx" => ("ss") => ("handles).
)
```

I want to remove them with vim, I am trying this:

```
%g/(/normal f(d%
```

but it leaves

> ( )

open, is there another way?

Comment: delete around ( instead:  :g/(/norm da(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should `d`elete `a`round `(` instead:

```
:g/(/norm da(
```